# How can I keep column widths in sync between multiple tables?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have two tables essentially built directly from their documentation. My Problem is, when an item is added and the row "Description" column is longer then the others, it extends this row out and all other rows in the table. However, the other table is now different. Here is what I mean.

Table 1:

```
| Section1 | Section2 | Section3
Row 1 is LONG | Row1 | Row1
Row 2         | Row1 | Row1
Row 3         | Row1 | Row1
```

Table 2:

```
| Section1 | Section2 | Section3
Row 1  | Row1 | Row1
Row 2  | Row1 | Row1
Row 3  | Row1 | Row1
```

Does this make sense? Is a better solution to keep it as one table and create headers to distinguish? If I were to give more information, its basically a profit and loss statement and the tables are separated.

Comment: You'd have to manually set column widths on all like tables.

Comment: Whether the tables should be separate depends on the content, not the appearance.

Comment: @isherwood this ended up helping me. More so the comment on why! Thank You

Comment: Feel free to post and accept an answer. I'm not sure I have an answer to post as the question is rather broad.